# Stored procedure changes not noticed by migrator

Tags: sql-server

Another team in my company is using an unknown-to-me migrator tool.
When I edit a stored procedure in SSMS (`ALTER PROCEDURE xyz...`), the migrator notices the change, and they push a button to send it on to Test and Prod.
However, if I use a custom C# app to connect to the SQL Server and run the same `ALTER`, the procedure is changed, but the migrator refuses to see the change. So the workflow stops.

I even changed my app to drop and recreate the procure from scratch, and the migrator still doesn't see the change.

`sys.objects` clearly has fresh dates in `create_date` and `modify_date`.

Any idea what this migrator might be using behind the scenes that might be causing my grief?

Comment: Without knowledge of the actual migrator there is not much we can do. Really you should contact their support. The only way I know to detect such changes is a server trigger.

Comment: The ways to tool might detect changes I can thing of are an SSMS add-in, DDL trigger, or server-side trace. With the the last 2 methods, it might filter for changes made by SSMS by examining the application name.

Comment: Wouldn't the potential trigger fire regardless if the ALTER came from SSMS or another app?

Comment: Depends how its written

Comment: @DanGuzman That sounds plausible.  Seems like a lot of extra work to create that limitation.

Comment: You could try spoofing the app name in your connection string with "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio" to see if the changes are detected.

Comment: @DanGuzman, if you want to post that as a real answer, I'll mark it.  Re"mark"ably, that worked :)  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @KurtisLininger, just when I think I've seen it all ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ways the tool might detect changes are an SSMS add-in, DDL trigger, or server-side trace. With the the last 2 methods, SSMS-only changes might be filtered by examining the application name.

Try specifying application name "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio" in your SqlClient connections string. That should work if schema changes are captured by a filtered DDL trigger or trace.